# ORC hive table which is already performed the ACID transactions(DELETE/UPDATE) is not able to read from Presto?

Tags: hive, presto

I am having problems trying to read from Pesto:

```
presto> select * from DEFAULT.MYDIM;
Error: Query 20190722_165050_00066_7g652 failed: Hive table 'default.mydim' is corrupt. Found sub-directory in bucket directory for partition: <UNPARTITIONED>


presto> SELECT * FROM DEFAULT.hello_acid;
Query 20190722_171313_00080_7g652, FAILED, 11 nodes
Splits: 16 total, 0 done (0.00%)
0:01 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20190722_171313_00080_7g652 failed: Hive table 'default.hello_acid' is corrupt. Found sub-directory in bucket directory for partition: load_date=2016-03-02
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Presto currently does not support ACID/Transactional tables, unless they're fully VACUUM-ed. You can track this feature request at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/576

Currently you can read such tables using [Starburst Presto](https://www.starburstdata.com/starburst-presto-sql/) 323e.

Comment: I have tested this, Presto 323-E.0 version is able to read the ORC format ACID/Transnational hive tables.
Our Cluster has :Hive metastore version 3 and HDP-3.X